# Error from Firefox on HTML: typeerror:vlc.playlist is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, video, vlc, video-player

I have written a code for a vlc player in HTML and JavaScript to stream live video, and it works perfectly fine in IE but when I try it in Firefox an error comes up saying `typeerror:vlc.playlist is undefined` I went over my code over and over and made changes and nothing worked.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Vids</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body onload='player("rtsp://admin:admin@stanthonys.tjcsys.com:8554/CH001.sdp");' id="Video">

<div id="player">
    <object type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
      id="vlcplayer"
      align="middle" 
      width="864px"
      height="540px" 
      classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">  
      <param name="Volume" value="100" />
      <param name="AutoPlay" value="true" />
      <param name="AutoLoop" value="false" />
    </object>
</div>

<div id="controls">
  <input type="button" onclick="play();" value="Play" />
  <input type="button" onclick="pause();" value="Pause" />
  <input type="button" onclick="stop();" value="Stop" />
  <input type="button" onclick="mute();" value="Mute" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var vlc = document.getElementById("vlcplayer");
    function player(vid) {
    try {
        var options = new Array(":aspect-ratio=16:10", "--rtsp-tcp", ":no-video-title-show");
      var id = vlc.playlist.add(vid,'Video',options);
      vlc.playlist.playItem(id);
      vlc.video.fullscreen = true;
      //vlc.video.toggleFullscreen();
    }
    catch (ex) {
      alert(ex);
    }
    }       
    function mute(){
    vlc.audio.toggleMute();
  }

    function play(){
    vlc.playlist.play();
  }

    function stop(){
    vlc.playlist.stop();
  }

    function pause(){ 
    vlc.playlist.togglePause();
  } 

  function fullscreen(){
    vlc.video.toggleFullscreen();
  }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone see a problem?

Comment: Again and again, **Javascript** is not **java**. They are two completely different programming languages. Tag removed.

Comment: `document.getElementById("vlcplayer")` will give you the HTMLElement object, which has no idea about any "playlist" property.

Comment: [*Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding** of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work.*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) That's a Javascript error, not an HTML one.

Comment: When I first had the error I tried to create an ID for the Video tag in this line = "var id = vlc.playlist.add(vid,'Video',options);" but after doing that the error stopped but the video wouldn't load.

Comment: Is this plugin installed on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know "embed" tag is used for Firefox,Chrome and "object" tag is used for IE.
Check for reference

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
           version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
           pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
           id="vlc"
           autostart="yes"
           toolbar="true"
           loop="yes" width="600" height="400"
           target="yourvideo/stream" />
```